# Comparing local file against checksum using Net::HTTP in Ruby without downloading full file

Tags: ruby, http-headers, checksum, fingerprint, net-http

Without being able to control or add headers server-side, is it possible to compare a local checksum against a remote file without downloading the entire file and comparing checksums using Ruby and Net::HTTP?

I'm populating a disk with files using a class I've written using Net::HTTP and would like to increase my bandwidth-thriftiness via comparison of the remote file against a SHA256 sum of my local file; I only want to download a remote file when my local copy doesn't match the remote version.

Here are my assumptions:

- The filenames may be the same, but the contents may differ.
- The 'Last-modified' date in the HTTP headers is not a good indication of a change - a `cp /dir_a/file1.tar /dir_b/file2.tar` results in identical checksums, but differing 'Last-modified' times.
- HTTP header Etags are not a good indicator: http://example.org/file1.tar and http://example.iana.org//file1.tar may have different Etags for the same file.
- HTTP header Etags are not entirely standard -- while EC2 uses md5sums to generate their Etags, other hosts may not.  This makes local generation of this tagging value difficult.
- Maintaining a hash/dictionary of hostname-to-Etag implementations is unwieldy and a bad approach.

While I'm relatively certain that the server-side software would have to provide a facility for doing a file/tag/checksum comparison to accomplish this goal (e.g. a checksum field in the header or separate look-up file), I would like confirmation of my assumptions before abandoning this pursuit.  I've left out my existing code to avoid distraction, as I'm looking to how to approach implementation.

Comment: interesting; I believe not (I guess it is the reason many sensible files such linux distros are distribuited with a checksum file), but I am curious if there is some "magic" trick

Comment: There is no standard for the creation of ETags -- they can be different on each server in a farm (for example, when they're based upon the filesystem inode of the file), and the last-modified time may vary across different servers.

There is no mechanism to request that a web server provide a hash of a particular file -- this would be an excellent manner to execute a denial of service against a web server.

Some object storage systems (such as Amazon S3) compute hashes when an object is stored and maintain it in metadata, but you're not going to find it in a web server by default.

Comment: @NevDull sure, it could be used to generate load on a server if it the resultant checksum wasn't cached (e.g. the time of a shasum5.12 on an i7:  `shasum5.12 ubuntu-12.04.1-server-amd64.iso  2.16s user 0.36s system 87% cpu 2.870 total`), especially for large files or a large list of files.  I was pretty sure that I'd be answering my own question when I opened it (as I did some research before asking).  Unless someone has some clever hack or 'magic' as @ProGNOMmers mentions, I'll just post my own research and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately for my use case, there's not a way to get pre-calculated checksums using standard HTTP headers or via the Net::HTTP request.

**Solutions**:

If you're in control of the server, you can add arbitrary headers, such as with [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

Alternatively, one could create and expose a structured dictionary file with key/value pairs for files/checksums, such as the following (cursory) example in JSON:

```
{ "md5-files": [
    {"file1" : "60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3"}, 
    {"file2" : "18ac6fe7ca693bb1767982e2eb3bbd0d")
]}
```

If one was going to mirror the same file on a plethora of servers, it might be worth building such a structured array *locally* and only use one server to signal that the file has changed *remotely* (e.g. master-download-server-1 downloads the file from http://example.org/file1, compares it to its local version, then updates a file.  This file could be parsed by slave-download-server1, slave-download-server2 to determine if they should send requests to example.org (or master-download-server-1 itself).

Finally, as I download often from Amazon's S3, I went with only option that I can use while acting as a client-only service: relying on the *etag* returned in the headers.  Unfortunately, the documentation for this is *not great*, but here's a rough snippet of my approach:

```
...
#I actually call my own encryption-helper, filename-parsing methods, 
#but meta-code for the sake of example:
def example_file_getter(uri, docroot, file)
    checksum = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(file))

    uri = URI.parse(uri)
    http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
    response = http.request(request)

    if response['etag'] != nil
        etag = response['etag'].gsub!(/\"/,'')
    end

    if etag == checksum
      file_existed = true
    end

    if ! File::exists?(destination) && ! file_existed
    ...actually fetch the file    
...
```

[again, meta-code; this is a summary of the important bits that are relevant to my original question]

Again, the etag documentation is not great and I fully expect Amazon to change this without warning at some point.  From what I've pieced together from various [forum responses](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=203510#203510) (!!) from Amazon staffers, the general algorithm for the tag is as follows:

1. If the file is less than 5GB and was streamed/non-'multipart'-uploaded to the server, the etag is likely the md5 of the uploaded file.
2. If the file is >5GB or uploaded via 'multipart', etag is seemingly the final chunk of the uploaded file, denoted by md5-#, where # is the part of the file (e.g. 3 chunks of uploaded files would look like 18ac6fe7ca693bb1767982e2eb3bbd0d-3 in the header).

Not perfect, but if your remote hosts follow a predictable pattern, inspect the headers and hope for the best.